# combining dataframes, and adding values of common elements

Tags: mysql, excel, database, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple data sets like this
data set 1

**index| name | val|**

```
1 |  a   | 1  | 
2 |  b   | 0  |
3 |  c   | 3  |
```

data set 2

**index| name | val|**

```
1 |  g   | 4  | 
2 |  a   | 2  |
3 |  k   | 3  |
4 |  l   | 2  |
```

I want to combine these data sets in such a way that if the both the data sets have a row with a common element name, in this example, "a",  i want to have only a single row for the combined dataset, where the value is sum of that a and this a, in this case the combined row a would have a val of 3 (2+1). index number for elements does not matter. is there an effective way to do this in excel itself? I'm new to querying data, but im trying to learn. If i can do this in pandas(i'm trying to make myself familiar in this language) or sql, I will do so. My data sets are of different sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
df3 = df1.groupby('name').sum().add(df2.groupby('name').sum(), fill_value=0).reset_index()
df3['val'] = df3.fillna(0)[' val']+df3.fillna(0)['val']
df3 = df3.drop([' val'], axis=1)
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
    name   index   val
0    a     3.0     3.0 
1    b     2.0     0.0 
2    c     3.0     3.0 
3    g     1.0     4.0 
4    k     3.0     3.0 
5    l     4.0     2.0
```

Comment: this was really helpful!. another question. suppose I want to include a second quantifier that stays the same. for example I have name, and gender. I want the name along with the gender as well. is there an easy way to include this?

Answer (score 2):

IN Sql you can try below query:

```
select name,sum(val)
from
(select index,name,val from dataset1
union all
select index,name,val from dataset2) tmp
group by name
```

In Pandas:

```
df3=pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)
df3.groupby(['name']).sum()
```